# How to expand sub-folders when a folder is opened in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I dont know how sohuld describe that but I wonder how can fix this. I am in doubt asking under correct tag

I want to see my subfolder independently of my parent folder.

Anyone can clarify this ?

This is what is default

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This only happens if the outer folder (`components` in your case) only has one element, so you're not losing any information.

But you can still disable this behavior with

```json
"explorer.compactFolders": false,
```

Comment: Thank you I wasn't know what should I do. this is more better for me